# Why isn't f(x^2) a horizontal stretch of f(x) by a factor of "1/x"?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I know this question seems silly, but it came to mind while reading about transforming functions. Is the statement "y=f(kx) results from scaling the graph of y=f(x) horizontally by a factor of 1/k" not applicable when k=x? A thorough explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, $x$ is an independent variable. So it doesn't really make sense to say that you've stretched the graph by $1/x$.

Comment: This is a really good question. I have a feeling that this sort of stretching doesn't exactly make sense globally, but I wonder if it's "locally" true, whatever that may mean.

Comment: I think that the answer to your question is that it is. After all, $1/x$ gets small, and a stretch by a small amount is a squashing. Look at what happens with $\sin(x^2)$ for larger and larger $x$.

Comment: @Lubin nice example, but how does this work for say $f(x)=x$? I suppose for $x$ negative we must also discuss a horizontal reflection as a type of 'horizontal stretch'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider for $x$ positive that $f(x^2)$ is simply a variable horizontal stretch. That is for $0<x<1$, you get a horizontal 'widening' and for $x>1$ you get a horizontal 'narrowing'. And (see my comment above) you have to remember that for $x$ negative, you have to take the positive $x-$axis values and reflect them over the $y-$axis. So for example this is how you would apply your rule to $f(x)=x$.

Comment: With your answer (and a little visualization using desmos) the idea of a "variable horizontal stretch" and the reflection over the y-axis for negative x became very clear. Thanks for the insightful answer!

Answer (score 0):

In the context discussed in the book, it is assumed that $k$ is a constant. So setting $k=x$ is not allowed as we are considering $x$ to be a variable.